# How to troubleshot a windows Service not starting when installed with Wix

Tags: .net-core, installation, wix, windows-services

I've a windows service in .Net Core that gets installed through a WIX setup.

Currently, when I register it manually:

```
sc create MyService binPath= "D:\My\Path\Release\MyService.exe" DisplayName= "MyService" start= auto
```

It works perfectly and with success. But in my WIX setup, I've the following setup:

```
  <Component Id="Xms_HostService" Guid="72044696-3E92-4928-BC6D-5A9C3ABB924A" SharedDllRefCount="yes">
    <File Id="MyService.exe" 
          Name="MyService.exe" 
          KeyPath="yes" 
          Vital="no" 
          Compressed="default" 
          DiskId="1" 
          Source="$(var.buildDirectory)\MyService.exe" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="MyService" 
                    Name="MyService" 
                    Type="ownProcess" 
                    Interactive="no" 
                    Start="auto" 
                    Account="LocalSystem"
                    ErrorControl="critical" 
                    Vital="yes" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                    Start="install"
                    Wait="no" />
    <ServiceControl Id="Uninstall" 
                    Name="StopService" 
                    Stop="both" 
                    Remove="uninstall" />

  </Component>
  <Component Id="MyService_Files" Guid="4DC25232-0B8D-4C16-ABC9-5BD5B45D0358" SharedDllRefCount="yes">
    <File Id="MyService.dll" Name="MyService.dll" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.buildDirectory)\MyService.dll" />
    <File Id="MyService.dll.config" Name="MyService.dll.config" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.buildDirectory)\MyService.dll.config" />
    <File Id="MyService.runtimeconfig.json" Name="MyService.runtimeconfig.json" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.buildDirectory)\MyService.runtimeconfig.json" />
    <File Id="MyServiceCore.dll" Name="MyServiceCore.dll" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.buildDirectory)\MyServiceCore.dll" />
  </Component>
```

It fails with the following error:

```
[B9A8:B850][2023-05-11T14:46:53]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to find payload: MyAppMsi in working path: C:\WINDOWS\Temp\{5B0118D2-90A3-4CF2-8793-79EA34A746D4}\MyAppMsi and unverified path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\MyAppMsi
```

If I just comment the `ServiceControl` start-service(which mean it doesn't get started by the setup, the setup finishes, but when I try to start the service, I get this error:
[image]

I've looked up those errors, they seems to indicate that some files could not be found.
But using winmerge, to compare my release output and what the setup has generated, I cannot see important missing files(I see a lot of deps.json or xml or pdb, but they all seems to be some build files).

I can't find anywhere(windows logs, my app logs) which DLL cannot be found.

Does anybody knows how to get more debug information on such issue?

I just found a Log file:

```
Rolling back assembly 'C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyApp\Bin\MyService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   assemblypath = C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyApp\Bin\MyService.exe
   logfile = C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyApp\Bin\MyService.InstallLog
Unable to create an instance of the my.app.MyService.MyServiceInstaller installer type.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
The inner exception System.TypeInitializationException was thrown with the following error message: The type initializer for '1' threw an exception..
The inner exception System.TypeLoadException was thrown with the following error message: Could not load type '' from assembly 'System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'..
```

But it doesn't help me much. I'm not sure if it's normal to have something related to "System.Configuration.Install" in Version 4.0.0 ?